# Connecting android application using Nodejs Restful API to Local mongoDB database and store data in Mongodb (via WiFi)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, android-studio, express, rest

Hello Stackoverflow fam,
I am working on **android application**, wherein the data entered from the app needs to be transferred to my remote **Mongodb database**, for this I am trying to develop **Restful API** using express js.

Now I am stuck in between on how to integrate the **front end app** to **node js** and **mongo db**

Kindly provide any reference documents/ tutorials which helps me understand the complete overview of it.

(I know the my problems seems too broad, but could'nt find any support online)..

Answer (score 1):

Try [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/). It's a best way to establish communication between node.js application/service and mongoDB.